# How to use variable (with value) as array name?

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, variables, copy

Is possible make this with jQuery?

http://jsfiddle.net/r9fY8/

**jQuery Code**

```
var bla = [ "hello", "world", "!" ];
var foo = 'bla';
foo = new Array();
alert(foo[0]); // how to return 'hello'?
```

Using deep copy (or any method):

```
var bla = [ "hello", "world", "!" ];
var foo = 'bla';
myarray = $.extend(true, {}, foo);
alert(myarray[0]); // how to return 'hello'?
```

**@edit:**

This example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rafuzeles/r9fY8/7/

**html**

```
<div class="mydiv" id="bla">Go</div>
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv_name_of_array">Go 2</div>
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv_some_array">Go 3</div>
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv_another_array">Go 4</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.mydiv').click(function () {
    var bla = ["hello", "world", "!"];
    var mydiv_name_of_array = ["hel", "wor", "ffs"];
    var mydiv_some_array = ["Hi", "Cat", "Dog"];
    var mydiv_another_array = ["Green", "Black", "Nice"];
    var mydiv_name_of_array = ["Air", "Plane", "Good"];

    var div_id = this.id;
    var myarray = $.extend(true, {}, div_id); // div_id = name of array

    alert(myarray[0]); // how to return value of array?
});
```

Comment: What you are trying to do here?

Comment: `var foo = bla.slice(0)`

Comment: I update post, view example [jsfiddle.net/rafuzeles/r9fY8/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/rafuzeles/r9fY8/7/), I need use id as name of array that already have value.

Comment: I updated my answer below. I'm 99% sure it's what you're looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about: http://jsfiddle.net/r9fY8/10/

```
$('.mydiv').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); // get id of clicked div
    var object_of_arrays = { // use an object so we can get named items
        bla : ["hello", "world", "!"],
        mydiv_name_of_array : ["hel", "wor", "ffs"],
        mydiv_some_array : ["Hi", "Cat", "Dog"],
        mydiv_another_array : ["Green", "Black", "Nice"]
    };
    var myarray = object_of_arrays[id]; // get the array with the same name as our id

    alert(myarray[0]); // returns hello, hel, Hi, or Green
});
```

I believe this solves the case you've requested. Be sure to mark this answer correct if you wouldn't mind - trying to improve my StackOverflow score. :)

Comment: Thanks for your sincere words! maybe I asked wrong manner, please view the real problem http://jsfiddle.net/rafuzeles/r9fY8/4/ i need call array based on div id

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are creating an array by javascript.

```
var bla = [ "hello", "world", "!" ];
```

You are initializing a variable and assigning a String value like:

```
var foo = 'bla';
```

You are assigning the value of foo to an empty array

```
foo = new Array();
```

Then

```
alert(myarray[0]);
```

it should return undefined.

This will do.

```
var bla = [ "hello", "world", "!" ];
var foo = bla;
alert(foo[0]);
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4U3sN/

Comment: bla is variable with same name of array, view whats I try make: http://jsfiddle.net/rafuzeles/r9fY8/4/

Answer (score 0):

//#1 with the single qoutes in foo = 'bla' it is not being treated as a variable but a string if you remove the single qoutes from it it will work

//#2 This needs to be removed entirely as it is clearing everything out of foo and so when it goes to alert foo it is empty

http://jsfiddle.net/r9fY8/1/

```
var bla = [ "hello", "world", "!" ];
var foo = 'bla'; //#1
foo = new Array(); //#2
alert(foo[0]); // how to return 'hello'?
```

Comment: var foo = bla; (bla is variable), var foo = somevalue, how to make this works? http://jsfiddle.net/rafuzeles/r9fY8/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r9fY8/8/

This is not the optimal way of doing this i know, however is this the functionality you are looking for here?

Comment: Nearly so, the arrays are in a file .js, I can not add them as a property of the div.

Comment: Then you could parse the arrays tostring and use javascript to insert them into the value attribute of the html element you want them to be bound to.

I just cant imagine that there is not a better way to do this.

Or you could just use a multidimensional JS array to keep track of what html element you want to bind to what JS array. That would probably be a cleaner way to go about it.

If you would be able to give me the js file in a fiddle somewhere i might be able to make some magic happen.

Comment: Sure, but this can take up much of your time, so I posted the problem summary... I'm using [github.com/syamilmj/Options-Framework](https://github.com/syamilmj/Options-Framework) developing Wordpress themes, with options based on this [wptheming.com/2012/02/color-palettes](http://wptheming.com/2012/02/color-palettes), but I'm add some more options to change other fields (like txt, inputs, etc), based on click of link on admin page (I add skins to theme, and I need change all options off theme with one click, but for each ID i need of differents values, and I have more than 300 skins).

Comment: I read through that a couple of times and i didn't understand *Exactly* what you are needing done. You are trying to add options to a backend of wordpress to do what?